# Iterating Create NetCDF Raster Layer in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, netcdf, time, iteration

Recently I have updated my ArcGIS to 10.5 and I got stuck with a process that I used to do a thousand times before in 10.2.2 version.

I need to calculate zonal statistics from rasters stored in netcdf format and I need to process a lot of them. To do that, I used to create a table with time dimension values stored in netcdf using "make netcdf table view", so I was always sure that time is stored in a good format:

[image: example time table]

Then I was creating model with field value iteration so I was iterating every single date and creating raster from netcdf

[image: model iteration]

It was working well every time in the past and now for some reason it's not. I have noticed that in the Dimension Value list in make netcdf raster layer tool I can choose not only "Value" as it was before but I can also choose separate date

[image: Dimension Value]

the tricky thing is that in this list date is in other format and I think that it's my source of problem.

If I create time table directly from netcdf file, why the date is in other format in this two places?

Can anyone tell my how can I change the date format in ArcGIS?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have a similar problem with using 'select by dimension' tool where I am iterating through the field values. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you have inferred from your question, changing the date format might help.

to convert the date format in table 1 to match the drop down in screenshot 3, I suggest the following: add a new text field called dateNew. Then calculate the field with the following python snippet:

```
!time![8:] + "/" + !time![5:7] + "/" + !time![0:4] + " 00:00:00"
```

I assume this will fix it for you. Otherwise, I can edit my answer with a useful netcdf4 tutorial in ArcPy/python

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem by creating a table in excel with an appropiate date format.

Comment: If this answer solves your question, remember to mark it as "accepted". Yes, even if you answered yourself :) . Bonus points if you elaborate your answer a little bit to explain exactly how you fixed it: What is "an appropiate date format"? Then you'd have a formidable answer!